# http working, but www. does not

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, domain, vps

I have been hunting for an answer but I really cannot find anything on the subject most likely down to me searching the wrong things. I am fairly certain its something to do with the way I have setup the DNS records but I may be wrong.

As you can see below;

`bitcoinfaucet.pw` resolves and loads perfectly fine.

`www.bitcoinfaucet.pw` does not resolve or load at all.

I have managed to install my SSL certification, directing any traffic from port 80 (http) to port 443 (https), I dont think this was the issue because the issue was present prior to making these changes. I have provided my DNS settings in the screenshot below.

[image: Namecheap DNS Records]

This issue has really been frustrating me, and I really do hope one of you wizards can help me resolve it. I would be very, very appreciative.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I see the "Apache2 Debian Default Page". (And why on earth are you using Debian for anything security-sensitive?)

Comment: Should I not be using debian? Also, http works fine, www. does not. For me that is anyway.

Comment: It's personal preference, But I think your www should be a CNAME targeted to @

Comment: Thank you Oxy, I will be changing that over now. I also dont really know why I have used Debian, ever since I started fiddling with servers I have for some reason always used Debian and its always done the job. I am open for knowledge, so if there is a better solution then I would be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: Your DNS records are correct and working as is. Try restarting your browser or your computer. As for Debian, well, I wouldn't trust it or its derivatives for anything Bitcoin-related as I don't believe it's secure enough. My production Bitcoin servers are all on CentOS 7 with SELinux-enabled Bitcoin packages (of which I'm also the maintainer). This is _money_ we're talking about, and taking every possible precaution with it is just the right thing to do.

Comment: I'll take that into consideration Michael thank you. I will go ahead and do that, just to confirm and I dont want to sound stupid here. Both www. and http:// are working for you?

Comment: Yes, perfectly working. I checked them both before my original comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change www to be a [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) targeted to @ instead of an A record. Leave the @ as an A record.

An exception to this would be when you want example.com to point to some different IP address than www.example.com. But if you setup www.example.com as a CNAME that points to example.com. then whatever you point example.com to then www.example.com will follow.

example:
[image]

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/308a32d8d86292fd29a5ef6427be26ca.png, let me know if thats what it should be. Appreciated.

Comment: The value should just be `@`. Unless that is what you put in and it's just showing this value for your convenience.

Comment: then allow 48 hours for dns to resolve (but try an `ipconfig /flushdns` in about an hour and give it a try)

Comment: Shows as impossible, the field 'Value' states the following (INVALID_ADDR : '@' should not be an IP/ URL for CNAME record.(host name: @)). Meaning, the value can only be a domain name?

Comment: I am so confused now, you just told me the CNAME should be an @, your screenshot shows the CNAME as www then the domain, not @ then the domain?

Comment: Also should have a serveralias for www.bitcoinfaucet.pw

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, You're right, you cannot use `@ ` as the value, looks like you have to use the actual domain value. my bad.

Comment: No problem, sound for that. Just to confirm, it should show like this; CNAME Record, Host: @, Value: bitcoinfaucet.pw. I am just concerned that the @ should be www like the screenshot you provided. Here are my .conf files also (https://i.gyazo.com/062fd2a0db2349d1d2ae769d910ba64d.png) and (https://i.gyazo.com/ff2c52606d17f46cc7e0824f1ed6095c.png)